# There is a way to NOT center the first element on a Carrousel View using .NET Maui

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, carousel, maui

I'm using a Carrousel View to display a images

There is the result :

[image]

This is fine but I want the first at the start of the screen like this :

[image]

There is the xaml :

```
<StackLayout>
   <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Carte, Mode=TwoWay}" IndicatorView="indicatorView2" PeekAreaInsets="100" HeightRequest="200" >
      <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
         <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="10" />
      </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
      <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:DataType="DTO:CategorieMenu">
            <StackLayout>
               <Image Source="{Binding ImgSource}" HeightRequest="150" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
               <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource MainPageLabelStyle}"/>
            </StackLayout>
         </DataTemplate>
      </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
   </CarouselView>
</StackLayout>
```

I tried a lot of things but I can't find what to do.
Did someone know how to do this ?

Comment: If you want more than one visible at a time, then use a Horizontal CollectionView instead of a CarouselView. Won't get the "snap"  to each position, but lets people scroll as far as they want. That's the user expectation, when more than one item is visible.

Comment: Can I have an Indicator View using a CollectionView ?

Comment: Sorry, there is no indicator. You'd have to invent a View that did what you want, and change it on CollectionView's Scrolled event. Maybe download [Maui source](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/tree/main), find CarouselView, figure out how it does IndicatorView.

Comment: I tried to create a custom CarouselView but it didn't works. My goal is to make it disappear the gap from the left side like in my first screenshot. I tried to change all ItemSpacing, Margin, Padding ect.... I know the CollectionView is the good one to resolve that but I want to keep the IndicatorView

Comment: Maybe `<DataTemplate ...> <AbsoluteLayout> <StackLayout Margin="-100,0,0,0" ...>`. Does that succeed in adjusting to left? Do the items show ok, or do they get clipped by that `-100`? If you are able to get it to look good on one device, by finding an appropriate number, I can show how to dynamically calculate that negative left margin in code behind, to `-(screenwidth - itemwidth) / 2`.

Comment: It change in the data template so that change the position of my image, not the position of the whole DataTemplate. When I put a BackgroundColor on the StackLayout inside the DataTemplate, I can see it is center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something to do what I want but I think a proper way exist :

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Carte, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="-170,0,0,0" IndicatorView="indicatorView2" PeekAreaInsets="180" HeightRequest="200" >
    <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="DTO:CategorieMenu">
            <VerticalStackLayout >
                <Image Source="{Binding ImgSource}" HeightRequest="150" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource MainPageLabelStyle}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can just remove the `ItemSpacing="10"`**. I created a new project to test your code and reproduced the problem.

Before I removed the `ItemSpacing="10"`, the effect:

[image]

And after I removed the `ItemSpacing="10"`, the effect:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
        <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Carte, Mode=TwoWay}"  IndicatorView="indicatorView2" PeekAreaInsets="100" HeightRequest="200" >
            <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="DTO:CategorieMenu">
                    <VerticalStackLayout >
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" HeightRequest="150" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource MainPageLabelStyle}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

Comment: Thank's for your answert, I tried your code but it doesn't change anything...

Comment: But it really worked in my project. And I tried the same code in the xamarin project and it  has a different effect which is one page center and a half at left and right. @AlexandreS.

Comment: Worth noting that the carousel control (in my experience) is one of the least consistent available in MAUI, it is especially bad on Mac (when resizing) and Windows (where it's not really a carousel just works like a Horizontal ListView almost)

Since it's so different on each platform that might explain why you were both seeing different results with the same code